# Why am I unable to Git push even though I've local commits that are yet to be pushed

Tags: git, egit

My eclipse workspace

[image]

Github repo

[image]

My workspace has few changes that I want to push to github. I've already commit'd them. Wen I try Push from eclipse, I get the below

[image]

**I am not sure what I am doing wrong**

When I right click on the project Team>Switch To>Other..., I see the below (hoping this would help)

[image]

---

EDIT 1

Below is the History on my project. What I want is to merge the 2 commits *above* `b697278` to `b697278` (as that is what is there on github).

[image]

Comment: It looks like maybe you are not on a branch? So maybe egit doesn't know how to push to origin. A local branch usually has remote tracking set up which specifies how to push to origin. If your HEAD is currently detached, there is no place to find upstream tracking information.

Comment: @tcovo pls see my edit 1

Comment: I'm guessing that your goal is to push your two new commits to `master` on origin. Normally, the situation you want to be in for doing that is to have your local `master` checked out, and have your new commits on your local master, making your local master be 2 commits ahead of origin/master. Once you're in that situation, you would be able to push. So how do you get there? You need to check out your master branch, then reset it to 327de48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've created your new commits while not being on the master branch - your HEAD and MASTER are pointing to a different commits. All you have to do is to merge you new commits into MASTER. Here are the commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge 327de48
```

Once your new commits are in the master your push should work, because git will see the difference between local and remote master.